# Find the library that a specific function is defined in

Tags: c++, function

Somebody sent me a piece of C++ code, and it includes some headers and functions that I'm unfamiliar with. I want to find which header file defined a particular function. For example, I have these headers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
```

and I want to know witch of them defined this function:

```
tcgetattr
```

or which of them defined this struct:

```
termios
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I don't mean this in a snarky way, but: searching for the unfamiliar function on the intarwebs answers this question pretty reliably. (e.g., [`tcgetattr` is probably defined in `termios.h`](http://www.bing.com/search?q=tcgetattr&src=IE-TopResult&FORM=IE11TR&conversationid=90293EEDAF044A04BE801D1B1B830CFB))

Comment: @Lilshieste did you ever use eclipse cdt ? in eclipse cdt when you put your mouse cursor on a function it open a window and show some details about that function , but it did not say the header file of it , i want some way like this to find header !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tcgetattr` is a "get attribute" function from `termios.h`. The `termios` structure is also from that header as I would have thought was self-evident by virtue of the fact it shares the name.

See, for example, the Linux man page [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tcgetattr).

If you're looking as to which headers contain arbitrary functions, I usually (in UNIX-like operating systems) just `grep` in known locations, something like:

```
grep tcgetattr /usr/include/*.h /usr/include/*/*.h
```

(or using the recursive option of `grep`, or `find` to search everywhere).

Comment: "tcgetattr" was just a example the code have a lots of unfamiliar function i want find the header of all of them!

Comment: i'm using linux too, and its worked for me . thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A general method to find out where a function is declared, if you don't know where it's supposed to be:

- Create a C++ source file that contains just those lines. Let's call it `test.cc`.
- Compile with file with the `-E` option.

  ```
  g++ -E -o test.out test.cc
  ```
- Look for the function you want to track in `test.out`. From there, you can track down which `.h` file it came from.

Comment: i did it , and i find out your mean , but it did not show all function , but thank you this way solved another problem for me !